# transclude and Require on Angular4

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm trying to convert this component of angularJs 1.6 to angular 4 and I can't find the solution for `require` and `transclude`:

Here AngularJs version:

```
const partnerTabComponent = {
  selector: 'ypUiPartnerTab',
  controller : PartnerTabController,
  template,
  transclude: true,
  require: {
    parent: '^ypUiPartnerTabs'
  },
  bindings: {
    label: '<'
  }
}
```

And here Angular version:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'yp-ui-partner-tab',
  templateUrl: './partner-tab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./partner-tab.component.less']
})
export class PartnerTabComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() label: any

  constructor() { }
}
```

I want to add `transclude` element and `require`, in this Angular version.

It maybe very easy, but I can't find the solution right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `require` in `angular`, you can however inject the parent component into your child component. If the child component is not inside the parent, your application will throw an error:

```
@Component({...})
export class PartnerTabComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private readonly partnerTabs: PartnerTabsComponent) {}

}
```

For the `transclude` bit, I believe you can use the `ng-content` tag:

If you have a parent component template like this:

```
<yp-ui-partner-tab>
  <div>this is sparta!</div>
</yp-ui-partner-tab>
```

You can render your 'sparta' inside your `partner-tab` at the position where you place your `ng-content` tag:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'yp-ui-partner-tab',
  template: `
      <div>What is this?</div>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class PartnerTabComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private readonly partnerTabs: PartnerTabsComponent) {}

}
```